Not able to perform an ANOVA test with a time series objects due to different residual lengths (R)
I am performing a general-to-specific procedure. I want to check the joint significance of all the insignificant variables.
I have a general model with all the variables, none removed, a model_x
I have a second model with ONLY insignificant variables (and the dependent one), a model_y
The problem is, I have a time series object, an ARDL model with lags.
In the general model, model_x, one of the variables has 4 lags.
In the second model, that same variable has only 3 lags (because one of them was significant in the general model)
What I want to do now is that I want to compare both of those, model_x and model_y using the ANOVA function but I can't due to the different number of residuals.
'''

length(residuals(model_x))


[1] 115


length(residuals(model_y))


[1] 116
'''

I have no idea how to resolve this, help would be greatly appreciated
